# Sessions randomly expire

Tags: session, laravel, session-cookies

I have a wierd problem with my project. When user logs in to web application expiration time of laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN are set at current timestamp.

Problem is that users randomly are logged out. I think that problems lies in session cookies and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Does someone knows where's the problem

Here is my session config:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false
```

Comment: Take a look at laravel-caffine